# CodeIgniter Pagination Problem

Tags: php, codeigniter

Helo. I’m trying to make a items pagination. I have 3 function, first displaying category, 2nd displaying sucategory. 3rd displaying items is cold get_books_by_subcategory. 3rd function get a segment->url(3) argumnet, i want to make a pagination in the same function. but i cant do it.

This is functions code in controller:

```
function get_category()
    {

        $query = $this->Kategorie_model->get_category();
        $this->response['podkategorie'] = '';
        $this->response['kategorie'] = '';
        $podkategorie = '';




        if($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            foreach($query->result() as $item)
            {
                $podkategorie = $this->get_sub_category($item->CAT_ID);

                $this->response['kategorie'] .=  $this->load->view('Ksiegarnia/left', array('kategorie' =>$item, 'podkategorie'=>$podkategorie), true);
            }
        }

        $data = $this->response['kategorie'];
        return $data;

    }





     function get_sub_category($id)
    {


           $this->response['wynik'] = '';


           $query = $this->Kategorie_model->get_sub_category($id);

           if($query->num_rows() > 0)
           {


                foreach($query->result() as $row)
                {

                   $link = site_url('ksiegarnia/get_books_by_subcategory/'.$row->SUBC_ID);
                    $this->response['wynik'] .= '<div class="subcat_name"><a href = "'.$link.'">'.$row->SUBC_Name.'</a></div>';

                }
           }
           else
           {
                $this->response['wynik'] = '<H1>BRAK DANYCH </H1>';
           }


            return $this->response['wynik'];
    }



    function get_books_by_subcategory()
    {
        $widok['center'] = '';
         $widok['left'] = $this->get_category();
         $widok['right'] = $this->load->view('Ksiegarnia/right', '', true);
          $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
        if(isset($id) and is_numeric($id))
        {
             $query = $this->Kategorie_model->get_books_by_subcategory($id, $this->uri->segment(4));


             if($query->num_rows() > 0)
             {

                foreach($query->result() as $item)
                {


                    $widok['center'] .=  $this->load->view('Ksiegarnia/get_books', array('data' =>$item), true);

                }
            }
            else
            {
                $widok['center'] = $this->load->view('Ksiegarnia/get_books', array('tytul' =>'<h1>brak danych</h1>'), true);;
            }

            $widok['center'] .= $this->pagination->create_links();
             $this->load->view('Ksiegarnia/index', $widok);

        }



    }
```

And this is my model:

```
function get_books_by_subcategory($id, $offset=0)
    {

                  $config['base_url'] = 'http://lukaszbielecki.cba.pl/ksiegarnia/CI/index.php/ksiegarnia/get_books_by_subcategory/'.$id;
                  $config['per_page'] = 7;
                  $this->db->where('SUB_CATEGORY_SUBC_ID', $id);


                  $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('books')->num_rows();
                  $config['num_links'] = 20;

                   $this->pagination->initialize($config);
         return   $this->db->get('books',$config['per_page'],$offset);
          //$wynik = $this->db->query("Select * from books where SUB_CATEGORY_SUBC_ID = '".$id."'");
          //return $wynik;
    }
```

The arguments in url is changing, but dispalyin only a items from first subcategory.
Help, please.

Answer (score 0):

On this line `$widok['center'] = $this->load->view('Ksiegarnia/get_books', array('tytul' =>'<h1>brak danych</h1>'), true);;` in your controller, you have an additional  semicolon `;` that is causing a syntax error.

Comment: So what. This line is execute only when num_row() has value lass than 0. If error never displayed its mean tha this "else" condition never executed. I have another problem...